# get the sentences that used to generate questions in python

Tags: python, nltk

i am really new to python and nltk, what i really need is to get the sentence that use in the tag combination. the sentence use in this code line

"if all(key in bucket for key in l1): "

please help me.

```
def genQuestion(line):
    """
    outputs question from the given text
    """
    if type(line) is str:  # If the passed variable is of type string.
        line = TextBlob(line)  # Create object of type textblob.blob.TextBlob

    bucket = {}  # Create an empty dictionary

    for i, j in enumerate(line.tags):  # line.tags are the parts-of-speach in English
        if j[1] not in bucket:
            bucket[j[1]] = i  # Add all tags to the dictionary or bucket variable

    if verbose:  # In verbose more print the key,values of dictionary
        print('\n', '-' * 20)
        print(line, '\n')
        print("TAGS:", line.tags, '\n')
        print(bucket)

    question = ''  # Create an empty string

    # Create a list of tag-combination

    l1 = ['NNP', 'VBG', 'VBZ', 'IN']
    l2 = ['NNP', 'VBG', 'VBZ']

    l3 = ['PRP', 'VBG', 'VBZ', 'IN']
    l4 = ['PRP', 'VBG', 'VBZ']
    l5 = ['PRP', 'VBG', 'VBD']
    l6 = ['NNP', 'VBG', 'VBD']
    l7 = ['NN', 'VBG', 'VBZ']

    l8 = ['NNP', 'VBZ', 'JJ']
    l9 = ['NNP', 'VBZ', 'NN']

    l10 = ['NNP', 'VBZ']
    l11 = ['PRP', 'VBZ']
    l12 = ['NNP', 'NN', 'IN']
    l13 = ['NN', 'VBZ']
```

## With the use of conditional statements the dictionary is compared with the list created above

```
if all(key in  bucket for key in l1): #'NNP', 'VBG', 'VBZ', 'IN' in sentence.
    question = 'What' + ' ' + line.words[bucket['VBZ']] +' '+ line.words[bucket['NNP']]+ ' '+ line.words[bucket['VBG']] + '?'
```

Answer (score 0):

declare this variable first

```
s = ""
```

and in the function "def genQuestion(line):"

```
 if question != '':
    s= question+line
    print(s)
```